# How is it possible to ensure a single delivery in a distributed system?

Tags: node.js, locking, distributed-computing

I have a distributed email delivery system that sends out emails regularly to a list of addresses, on specific date and times.

I have a bunch of servers polling the database and waiting for the right time to send the emails.

How can I ensure those servers won't send the same email at the same time to the same customer? Do I have to create some kind of a distributed lock mechanism here? Is there perhaps a better, more efficient way to do so? If not, what is the recommended best-practice for implementing this kind of  distributed lock (my current stack is node.js + postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Well, A possible work around is just, using consistent hashing, on the hash of (subject + time + whatever), and not performing the task, if it's not the right polling worker.

Distributed Locks, in of themselves are pretty inefficient and hard to scale, but I mean you can look into lamports bakery, token ring passing networks,outside of chubby all of them are total shit in terms of liveliness, chubby is pretty tricky to implement right too, you can also have like a lightweight quorum, but thats not efficient either.

TLDR, consistent hashing, is  probably the smart way to go, or honestly, I don't see why you don't have a single poller, that just forwards all the work to a load balancer, that will distribute the work,in a scheduled manner.